# Python program with an extension .ipynb/.py does not work when converted to .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create an executable of a program, that opens up a link and do the login in every half an hour and keep counting the time. It has been written in Jupyter Notebook. The code works fine in Jupyter(.ipynb)/.py but when converted to .exe it throws an error saying `"Fatal error Detected -Failed to execute script"`. The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from plyer import notification

i=1
while i<=20:
    notification.notify(
    title="Initiating Session Number {}".format(i),
    message='Marking Attendance',
    app_icon=r"C:\Users\91800\Downloads\Documents\automation\aut.ico", 
    timeout=6,  # seconds
    )
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get('https://120.72.92.102:10443/remote/login?lang=en')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))

    username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("credential")

    username.send_keys("pranjal.pathak")
    password.send_keys("zxc^567")

    driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```

I am getting the following error(sorry for the image quality, this is the best I could manage):

[image]

Comment: When you say "converted to .exe" what exactly do you mean? I.e. how are you 'converting' into a .exe?

Comment: I used the command prompt.
Used the command, "pyinstaller --onefile -w Automation.py".   Thanks for the edit by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, since no one replied to my question, I think is good if I clarify it myself since I have already figured it out.

I managed to make it work by making 2 changes-
1. Used win10toast for notifications instead of plyer
2. Made sure to import images while making an .exe from the command prompt. For this I used this command in command prompt:

```
pyinstaller -F --onefile -i "C:\user\.....(location of the image)" filename.py
```

This solved my problem gracefully.

Comment: I am using pyinstaller to convert .ipynb file to .exe file as i want my peers members to use it without depending on python but when i try to run the exe file i get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last): File "Bot.ipynb", line 232, in NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Two things to consider here are

I dont have this particular keyword "null"
my total line of codes are less than 232